# Geometry Problem on medians

Tags: geometry

The median $AA'$ of the $ABC$ meets the side $B'C'$ of the medial triangle $A'B'C'$ in $P$ and $CP$ meets $AB$ in $Q$. Show that $AB = 3 AQ.$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** let $R$ be on $CP$ such that $|CP|=|PR|$. Then $A'CAR$ is a parallellogram, so $AR \parallel BC$. Now use the similarity $\triangle BQC \sim \triangle AQR$.

Comment: Please complete the solution

Comment: @Viki, hints are not enough for you.

Comment: @Viki: please also show some of your own work. What are your difficulties?

Answer (score 0):

You can construct two additional parallelograms, equal to the parallelogram $AB'A'C'$ - one will be attached to the side $B'A'$ and include the vertex $C$ and the second one will be attached to the side $AC'$ and include two additional vertices $E$ and $H$.

The large parallelogram $ECDH$ will be divided by lines $AC'$ and $B'A'$ into three equal parts - parallelograms $EAC'H$, $AB'A'C'$ (original one, which is inside the triangle $\triangle ABC$), and $B'CDA'$. So, its diagonal $CH$ splits the lines $AC'$ and $B'A'$ with ratio $1:2$. The rest is simple...

Also, there is a number of methods to trisect a segment. If you are curious about that - please look at this [page](http://www41.homepage.villanova.edu/robert.styer/trisecting%20segment/).

Comment: @user133281 - your additional point $R$ is my additional point $H$ :)